# Terraform Object Lock Configuration: AccessDenied

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-modules, aws-iam-policy

I have this terraform script that works perfectly fine for the whole s3 module but it cannot create the Object lock configuration resource and returns the message :

```
error creating S3 bucket (bucket-name) Object lock configuration: AccessDenied: AccessDenied
Status code 403, request id: ..., host id: ...
```

Desite the message, the S3 bucket is actually created, but I still get this error, maybe there is something missing in the policy ?

Here is my code.

```
module "s3_bucket" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/s3-bucket/aws"
  version = "3.4.0"

  bucket                                = local.bucket_name
  ...
  object_lock_enabled                   = true

  attach_policy = true
  policy        = data.aws_iam_policy_document.voucher_s3_bucket.json

  versioning = {
    status     = var.status
    mfa_delete = var.mfa_delete
  }

  server_side_encryption_configuration = {
    rule = {
      apply_server_side_encryption_by_default = {
        kms_master_key_id = aws_kms_key.voucher_s3_bucket.arn
        sse_algorithm     = "aws:kms"
      }
    }
  }
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "s3_bucket_kms_key" {
  statement {
    sid     = "AllowPutRoles"
    effect  = "Allow"
    actions = ["kms:GenerateDataKey"]
    principals {
      identifiers = local.put_object_roles #we can use event_gateway iam_role for now
      type        = "AWS"
    }
    resources = ["*"]
  }
  statement {
    sid    = "AllowAdmin"
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "kms:*",
    ]
    principals {
      identifiers = [data.aws_iam_role.admin_role.arn, data.aws_iam_role.default_role.arn, data.aws_iam_role.automation_role.arn]
      type        = "AWS"
    }
    resources = ["*"]
  }
}

resource "aws_kms_key" "s3_bucket" {
  tags = {
    "s3_bucket" = local.bucket_name
  }
  enable_key_rotation = true
  policy              = data.aws_iam_policy_document.voucher_s3_bucket_kms_key.json
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_object_lock_configuration" "s3_bucket_object_lock_configuration" {
  bucket = local.bucket_name
  rule {
    default_retention {
      mode  = "GOVERNANCE"
      years = 10
    }
  }
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "voucher_s3_bucket" {
  statement {
    sid     = "DenyNoKMSEncryption"
    effect  = "Deny"
    actions = ["s3:PutObject"]
    principals {
      identifiers = ["*"]
      type        = "*"
    }
    resources = ["${module.voucher_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_arn}/*"]
    condition {
      test     = "StringNotEqualsIfExists"
      values   = ["aws:kms"]
      variable = "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption"
    }
    condition {
      test     = "Null"
      values   = ["false"]
      variable = "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption"
    }
  }

  statement {
    sid     = "DenyWrongKMSKey"
    effect  = "Deny"
    actions = ["s3:PutObject"]
    principals {
      identifiers = ["*"]
      type        = "*"
    }
    resources = ["${module.s3_bucket.s3_bucket_arn}/*"]
    condition {
      test     = "StringNotEquals"
      values   = [aws_kms_key.voucher_s3_bucket.arn]
      variable = "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption-aws-kms-key-id"
    }
  }

  statement {
    sid     = "AllowAdminDefault"
    effect  = "Allow"
    actions = ["s3:*"]
    principals {
      identifiers = [data.aws_iam_role.admin_role.arn, data.aws_iam_role.default_role.arn]
      type        = "AWS"
    }
    resources = [
      "${module.voucher_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_arn}/*",
      module.voucher_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_arn,
    ]
  }

  statement {
    sid     = "DenyDeleteActions"
    effect  = "Deny"
    actions = ["s3:DeleteBucket", "s3:DeleteObject", "s3:DeleteObjectVersion", "s3:PutBucketObjectLockConfiguration"]
    principals {
      identifiers = ["*"]
      type        = "AWS"
    }
    resources = [
      "${module.s3_bucket.s3_bucket_arn}/*",
      module.s3_bucket.s3_bucket_arn,
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You are already defining the object lock in the module call, there is no need to do it twice.

Comment: I only enabled it in the module following the documentation

Comment: Ah, yes, my bad, didn't read the resource name properly. :) What I would suggest then instead of using `local.bucket_name` to use an output from the module to get the bucket name and then reference that in the `aws_s3_bucket_object_lock_configuration` resource.

Comment: Same thing, I replaced the local.bucket_name with module.s3_bucket.s3_bucket_id and I'm still getting an Access denied.

Comment: Ok, but, I have just taken a look at the module and it can create the object lock: https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-s3-bucket/blob/master/main.tf#L324-L338. It might be better to try it that way instead of adding a completely new resource.

Comment: Isn't that what I actually did ? Creating a completely new resource for the lock configuration ?

Comment: You are, I am just suggesting to try and use the module for everything you need because it's already there. Are you enabling or disabling versioning with the `var.status`?

Comment: It's enabled, so maybe I should also create separate resources for server side encryptions and versioning and so on ?

Comment: That kind of defeats the purpose of using a module. :) Especially the one you are using as it's packed with everything you need. Maybe it's KMS key related, not sure.